# Optimise ASP.NET application IPhone and Android browsers for ASP.NET application

Tags: iphone, asp.net, android, mobile, mobile-safari

I have an ASP.NET (not MVC) application.

I would like to create a version that is optimised for browsers on the IPhone and on Android.

Some questions

- Is it possible to detect IPhone/Android when the site is accessed
- Are there any gotchas/tips for developing ASP.NET for these devices.

Answer (score 3):

We're using a combination of .net webforms and [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

For our viewstate, it's been pretty well neutered already so only minor stuff is going down to the device.

Bear in mind that there are around 3 different mobile api's.  Each of which has their own drawbacks.  You might want to investigate each.

Also, we took the approach that the mobile site was a completely different website than our standard one.  When the user comes in, we do some browser sniffing and push them to mobile if it matches with a link to move back to the full one if they want.

Answer (score 0):

Webforms aren´t good for mobile, it generates big pages because viewstate. And you can´t control rendering (some more in .net4).

You can detect device using a db of capabilities like [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) (I recommend [51degrees](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/)) o maybe using some like http://detectmobilebrowser.com/

I don´t know what kind of webapp but you could make a new app, maybe using MVC. Please look [this resource](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebAppToolkitMobile).

Comment: Although I didn't downvote, I just wanted to say that you do have a lot of control over rendering if your willing to forgo some of the controls like gridviews which are absolute hogs